# Opscenter doesn't show my key spaces

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I have Cassandra cluster (ver 2.0.12) and Datastax Agents 5.0.1. Also I using OpsCenter 5.1.0. In "Explorer" tab I see no keyspaces.
Query from CLI:

```
 SELECT keyspace_name FROM system.schema_keyspaces;
```

show my keyspaces. I try URL:

```
http://<cluster_url>:8888/<cluster_name>/keyspaces
```

that show me JSON output which conatain keyspaces info(i think), but "Explorer" tab still empty.

Comment: You should upgrade the agents to 5.1.0 and try again.  If you still see the issue comment here and we'll troubleshoot from there.

Comment: I've updates to 5.1.0 but still cannot see keyspaces in OpsCenter

Comment: When you say the Explorer tab is empty, do you mean that there are no keyspaces in the dropdown, or that when you choose a keyspace it does not show any data?  It's worth noting that the Data Explorer in OpsCenter is deprecated functionality, and you should use DevCenter instead: http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/devcenter

Comment: no keyspaces in dropdown. When i restart OpsCenter they appear after some time, but the disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Opscenter does not necessarily automatically connects to the local node to get the cluster information. You can review [this piece of documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscAdvConfig_r.html) to check what is in your configuration files, and update them properly. There can be multiple reasons why OpsCenter can't connect to your local instance.

Or you can use the wizard to add a cluster to manage. This should populate data properly into the config files.

Comment: thnx. While try to re-add cluster i saw in log info about my keyspaces, but cluster didnt created because of stange error [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825027/dataxtax-agent-error)