# Dataxtax Agent error

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

While adding existing cluster in OpsCenter I receive an error:

```
ERROR: Agent for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX was unable to complete operation (http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:61621/snapshots/pit/properties?): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil
```

On agent there is an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil
at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:541)
at clojure.java.io$fn__8551$G__8546__8558.invoke(io.clj:73)
at clojure.java.io$reader.doInvoke(io.clj:106)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$slurp.doInvoke(core.clj:6278)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at opsagent.backups.pit$read_properties.invoke(pit.clj:68)
at opsagent.backups.pit$enabled_QMARK_.invoke(pit.clj:106)
at clojure.core$eval37.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:107)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6609)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6582)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2852)
at opsagent.opsagent$post_interface_startup.doInvoke(opsagent.clj:102)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at opsagent.conf$handle_new_conf.invoke(conf.clj:198)
at opsagent.messaging$message_callback$fn__12316.invoke(messaging.clj:52)
at opsagent.messaging.proxy$java.lang.Object$StompConnection$Listener$7f16bc72.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.jgroups.client.StompConnection.notifyListeners(StompConnection.java:324)
at org.jgroups.client.StompConnection.run(StompConnection.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And cluster creation failed. Also i get this error during startup. I tried reinstall agent but in won't help

DataStax Agent version: 5.1.0

OpsCenter version 5.1.0

```
root@node1:~# java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
root@node1:~#
```

Content of address.yaml

```
stomp_interface: "YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY"
```

Content of opscenterd.conf

```
[webserver]
port = 8888
interface = 0.0.0.0
use_ssl = false
[logging]
level = INFO
```

<cluster name>.conf is absent, because cluster not added

Comment: How did you install Cassandra (deb/rpm or tarball)?

Comment: Could you please add the following files to you post: <cluster name>.conf, address.yaml and opscenter.conf. There have been some changes in OpsCenter 5.1 one of which was removing thrift from the agent this means there are some subsequent config file changes

Comment: Ok so from your config we can see that there's no ssl configured so thats good. As asked above, how did you install opscenter and the agents?

Comment: I've installed OpsCenter and Agents from http://debian.datastax.com. On another nodes all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem the agent is having is finding your installation of DSE on that node.  When it can't find DSE it can't get the archiving properties file to update and errors out.

This error message is unfortunately terribly unhelpful.  I've created a ticket to fix the error message (it's unfortunately private, but you can use this ticket number when discussing the issue with DataStax: OPSC-4826)

For a work around, try setting cassandra_install_location in your address.yaml file on that node.  After adjusting address.yaml please bounce the agent and you can retry that operation.

You can find a document listing this and more address.yaml config items here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html

Comment: cassandra_install_location in needed when Cassandra installed from tarball. But In my case cassandra is installed from deb.

Comment: Hi @Maxiko , can you try setting it anyhow?  Thanks.

Comment: Also useful to know, is to ensure that the identity that the agent is running under has read/write permissions to the cassandra archiving properties file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue will be with your Java installation. I believe you'll need Oracle Java, not OpenJDK.

This worked for me:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

Comment: I have 4 similiar nodes. On 1st node there is an error, but on the rest is ok!

Comment: On the Datastax website (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/install/installStandalone.html) it says:

Prerequisites

    Root or sudo access when installing as a system service, and if installing missing system dependencies.
    Latest version of Oracle Java SE Runtime Environment 7, not OpenJDK. See Installing the Oracle JRE.

Comment: you updated all 4 nodes? and java -version shows something like 

`ubuntu@localhost:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)`

Comment: I've updated only one, because on another nodes everything ok!